# Show/hide multiple buttons using ref in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have list of songs with play button. I want to toggle button text to play/pause accordingly.

I have set ref for play/pause `<span>` and trying to hide/show on button click.

```
 this.refs.play.hide().
```

But this is giving error

> Uncaught TypeError: _this.refs.play.hide is not a function
>       at Song._this.play

Here is my react component code.

```
class Song extends React.Component {
  play = (event) => {
    this.refs.play.hide()
    console.log(this.refs.play);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Song 1 <button onClick={this.play}><span ref="play">play</span> <span className='hide' ref="pause"> Pause</span></button></li>
          <li>Song 2 <button onClick={this.play}><span ref="play">play</span> <span className='hide' ref="pause"> Pause</span></button></li>
          <li>Song 3 <button onClick={this.play}><span ref="play">play</span> <span className='hide' ref="pause"> Pause</span></button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Player.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class Player extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isPlaying: false
    };
  }
  togglePlay = () => {
    this.setState({
      isPlaying: !this.state.isPlaying
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* actual player logic {this.props.songurl} */}
        <span>{this.props.songName}</span>
        <button onClick={() => this.togglePlay()}>
          {this.state.isPlaying ? "Pause" : "Play"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

> PlayerList.js

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import Player from "./Player";
export default class SongList extends Component {

  render() {
    const songs = [
      {
        name: "song 1",
        url: "google.com"
      },
      {
        name: "song 2",
        url: "google.com"
      },
      {
        name: "song 3",
        url: "google.com"
      },
      {
        name: "song 4",
        url: "google.com"
      },
      {
        name: "song 5",
        url: "google.com"
      },
      {
        name: "song 6",
        url: "google.com"
      }
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        {songs.map((song, key) => (
          <Player key={key} name={song.name} url={song.url} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have thousands of songs so its not possible to manage state

Comment: no we can do it you have to create an song component that will handle play pause and parent need to pas song data (urls) for playing songs.
will i'll give you example snippet.

Comment: check my edit and let me know if you do have any doubt.

Comment: I have multiple buttons and wants to update particular button text

Comment: So same way u can do it with component state